# Is it lawful for a Germany non profit company to extend an interest free loan of 300,000 Euro to a Ugandan citizen?

Tags: germany

A Germany non profit company signed a loan agreement in which it extended an interest free loan of 300,000 Euro to a Ugandan citizen. Can it enforce the loan agreement in Germany?

Comment: Is the Ugandan citizen in Germany, or are any of the Ugandan citizen's assets or sources of income im Germany?  If not, will Uganda or any other country where these things are located enforce a judgment of a German court?

Comment: Your headline and body ask two very different questions. It can be lawful and it can at the same time be unenforcable. Can you please ask one coherent question about this, so you get good focussed answers?

Answer (score 1):

- A non-profit would have a *charitable purpose* (Gemeinnützigkeit). This purpose may or may not cover interest-free loans as a means of achieving that purpose.
- If that loan is a contract, the contract is enforceable in court. Whether that is an Ugandan court or a German court depends on who sues and where they are. Easiest if the debtor and the creditor are both in the same country.
- A German court would *expect* contracts of this kind to be in writing, signed by representatives of both parties, but contracts *can* be less formal. The contract may have something to say about *Gerichtsstand* (the location of the court where suits are to be filed).